Typesctript Class Clonstructors parameters - How many max we can accomodate
export class Common_Class{
  Page1: Page1
   //....
  Page50: Page 50
  constructor(pageClass1: Page1, page2: Page2 .... 50){
    this.Page1= Page1
  }
}

I have a need to import 50 60 PageClass for Playwright for Common services. How many constructor parameters can I accomodate maximum like that in Typescript
Tried adding a few constructor parameters and they were good.. how much can i add more . What will happen if I add too much .. Loading/perf problems? Limitations on parameters ?
Why because it represents a single point representation of all available Pages within the framework without searching here and there .. This is how I would use without importing because it extends teh basic playwright test class.
When method of playwriight-bdd basiscally is co extended with test class of playwright
When('I navigate to ', async function ({Login_Page}, parameters) {
        Login_Page.anymethods();
});


There is not really a hard limit to the amount of arguments a constructor / function can receive. The questions here would be why? That's why you got marked to provide more details. I would recommend you to use an array, now you can access individual pages by index.

i updated the q above

The specification doesn't define a limit on function arity, but I think it's safe to assume that it cannot exceed the maximum length of an array (which is 2 ** 32 - 1) because rest parameters are collected into an array. If this answers your question, I can write it as one. If not, what did I miss?

ok .. let me testthen .. will accept as answer

This is an XY problem. Use an array--see the bottom of "Variable" variables in JavaScript. // BAD - DON'T DO THIS!!! var foo1 = 'foo'; var foo2 = 'bar';. If you want to work with 50 pages, you'll need to copy and paste your code 50 times, or pack those vars into an array sooner or later. So just do it right away and be done with it. But the question remains: why do you need 50 pages in the first place? That's also very unusual.

This could be a dupe of Is there a max number of arguments JavaScript functions can accept? if it weren't for the XY problem. The only time this question should matter is if you're spreading into an Array#push() call.

Also relevant: Are there guidelines on how many parameters a function should accept?. "A function that takes more than three or four parameters indicates there is another object hiding in there. You may need to create another object or data structure that includes these parameters" (e.g. an array).

@ggorlen .. never seen large app flows etc  ? just joined software industry ? freshie I guess...  this is small I have seen apps with 2 3 hundred different pages, regulatory dept's etc.

What do  you propose I do with array ? every function I write every step I write I go back and keep checking which index is it and try to know and go back and use it ? and what about people reading it ? keep constantly go back and check or take a print and mememorize which index is which page ? what kind of nonsensical reasoning is that ?

Are you all here to joke around are you are all really serious ?

The reason people suggest an array is that you example list Page1, Page2 etc which already suggests that pages don't have names but are a list. If that is not the case as your new snippet of login page suggests, you can use an object and get element with the keys. People try to be helpful, if you ask a question you will also need to bring some level of trust that people have your good at mind.
Your page count will grow, you should not add each page manually. There isn't really enough information to make good suggestions. But your pages are most likely already identifiable by url segments.

So you could have a property that is an object within Common_Class called pages.
Now you could get and set pages with e.g. common_class_instance.getPage("/login")

The solution to the XY problem is to provide context for what you're actually trying to achieve, because using Page1, Page2...Page4363 is not workable. The general solution is to use an array as I linked to in my previous comment, but if that isn't what you're looking for or you don't know how to implement that, please help us help you by zooming out and explaining your fundamental use case clearly. Like I also said, generally in tests you never have more than 1 or 2 pages at the most, so even using an array is very unusual.

@oliverwebr again .. nonsensical. you cant be true both ways and I have seen this many places with  noobs. You can't ask someone more details and also let other one have benefit of doubt that he understood what i did not explain.

@oliverwebr again someone downvoted the below answer - its superb trick of doing it .. you see what i am saying. They had enough context by now and they still downvoted  the answer why?. It serves the purpose i am talking about. Really really beautiful example. do contrast that with what and how ggorlen  approaching same

@oliverwebr the answer from ggorlen "If you want to work with 50 pages, you'll need to copy and paste your code 50 times, or pack those vars into an array sooner or later. So just do it right away and be done with it. But the question remains: why do you need 50 pages in the first place? That's also very unusual" assumes he fully understood the question .. and its neither an answer or a discussion .. its straightaway condescension

additionally lets say we want to bring trust .. then we ask details . any downvote if its incorrect  - later as part of larger panel or evaluation .. we should cancel the downvotes.

Not an answer for the direct op question, but this does provide an alternative approach to what they are trying to do.
Create a pages class that has all the pages within:
// pages.ts
import { Page } from '@playwright/test';
import { Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5} from 'where they are...'

export class Pages {
  page1 = new Page1(this.page);
  page2 = new Page2(this.page);
  page3 = new Page3(this.page);
  page4 = new Page4(this.page);
  page5 = new Page5(this.page);

  constructor(private readonly page: Page) {}
}

Then have a fixture that uses the Pages collection:
// myFixture.ts
import { Page, test as base } from '@playwright/test';
import { Pages } from 'pages.ts';

type TestFixture = {
  pages: Pages;
}

export const test = base.extend<TestFixtures>({
  pages: async ({ page }, use) => {
    const pages = new Pages(page);
    await use(pages);
  },
});

Then use that fixture in your test and the Pages collection you have exposed:
// myTest.spec.ts
import { test } from 'myFixture.ts';

test('Test something here', async ({ pages }) = > {
  await pages.page1.doSomething();
  await pages.page2.somethingElse();
});


Those who downvoted do we have any explanation ?

This does not work with standard classes as emitted with useDefineForClassFields

I don't see how this answers the question at all. OP wants to pass all those page instances as arguments to their constructor, not instantiate new ones.

@Bergi You are of course correct in that it does not answer the op in the question given, but does give an alternative approach to solving what they were attempting to do which I should have stated in my answer.  As for it won't work with useDefineForClassFields, most answers here won't work if they have to account for the millions of possible combinations of tsconfig ;)

The point is that this code with class fields does not work in standard JavaScript. As I understand the useDefineForClassFields documentation, this option will become the default for modern targets

@Bergi useDefineForClassFields  as i understand - is only for migration ? not newly contructed latest nodejs? if so it will still work now and in future also ?
Second - test('Test something here', async ({ pages }) = > {
this helps in non verbose and readable code .. and it satisfies the problem i am trying to solve

The specification doesn't define a limit on function arity, but I think it's safe to assume that it cannot exceed the maximum length of an array (which is 2 ** 32 - 1 and evaluates to 4294967295) because rest parameters are collected into an array.
While 50 or 60 parameters is highly unusual, the TypeScript compiler is still capable of handling even larger collections, so it should not cause a problem.
